# How do I show icons for oncreate menuitems in google glass "ok glass" voice menu inside the activity?

Tags: android, google-glass, google-gdk

I am trying to display icons for menu items created in an activity in google glass application.
Here is my code.

```
if (featureId == WindowUtils.FEATURE_VOICE_COMMANDS) {
getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.voice_menu, menu);
return true;
}
```

And my menu.xml

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >

    <item
        android:id="@+id/navigate"
        android:title="Navigate"/>
    <item
        android:id="@+id/back"
        android:icon="@drawable/icon2"
        android:title="Back"
        android:showAsAction="always|withText"/>
</menu>
```

But if i say "ok glass" it will show only menu title, no menu icon is shown. Please help me to proceed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With the "Ok Glass" menu (named Contextual Voice Command), you can't add any icon
With XE19 you can't add more than 6 items and custom the display of the "Ok Glass".

If you put an icon in your menu.xml, this icon will only appear if you use a classic menu calling this function :

```
openOptionsMenu();
```

If you use a voice command menu using the code below, the icon won't appear :

```
getWindow().requestFeature(WindowUtils.FEATURE_VOICE_COMMANDS);
```

Comment: I will update my answer to answer to be clearer. Call openOptionsMenu() instead, you will see the difference